# Differences between Log and Logger?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have seen people use this way:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.foo");
```

and I have seen the other way:

```
Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CLASS.class);
```

What's the differences behind them? Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

The call to Logger.getLogger is from the log4j api.

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.foo");
```

[Documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html)

---

The call to LogFactory.getLog() is from the commons-logging api.

```
Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CLASS.class);
```

[Documentation](http://commons.apache.org/logging/commons-logging-1.1.1/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/Log.html)

log4j is a logging framework, i.e. it provides the code to log messages. Commons-logging is an abstraction layer for logging frameworks, it doesn't log anything itself.

Comment: can you please provide a tutorial to learn the `common-logging` as the above link doesnot work now

Answer (score 0):

One way to view it is that the "logger" does the work to write to the log stream/file. (Verb)

The "log" is the contents of that stream/file. (Noun)